# Android выполнение запрососв

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Как сделать так чтобы запросы отправлялись не одновременно а последовательно, пока не будет получен ответ на предыдущий запрос(не важно какой допустим загрузить картинку по url) не отправлялся следующий?

Есть массив с данными(url'ы картинок), нужно пробежаться по нему и получить все картинки последовательно, использовал
цикл{
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {...}}}
но такая схема как я понимаю почти одновременно выполняет все запросы....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае удобно использовать [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    service.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             ...
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете заюзать [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), он как раз будет выполнять всё строго по очереди и в выделенном потоке

Answer (score 0):

Создай отдельный поток и в потоке выполняй синхронные запросы, а не асинхронные (тогда до завершения предыдущего запроса следующий не выполнится).